# j-unit testing Immutable Binary Search Tree add methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tostring

I have been attempting to build an immutable binary search tree data structure. Now that I have gotten so far in the development I am attempting to test the methods i have created. So far it is going well.

My add method as it stands:

```
@Override
public Set<T> add(T t) {
    if (t.compareTo(x) == 0) {
        return new Add<T>(x, left, right);
    } else {
        if (t.compareTo(x) < 0) {
            return new Add<T>(x, left.add(t), right);
        } else {
            return new Add<T>(x, left, right.add(t));
        }
    }
}
```

The toString which I think is causing the issue:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "";
}
```

and the unit test:

```
@Test
public void SetAddElements(){
    activeSet = newSet.add(1);
    assertEquals("The element(s) were not added!", 1 , activeSet.add(1));
}
```

However, my .add() method appears to fail my unit test. From what I have deduced the toString method of my Empty class returns white space which means instead of the result of my unit test returning (expected: <1>, ) it returns (expected: <1>, actual: <1 >). A minor difference but enough for the test to fail.

[junit test results and error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa2vL.png)

I have attempted to remove the toString method but obviously this just returns the default toString and attemoted to research using api and such but came up with nothing. I am struggling to phrase the question in an accurate representation of the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should implement the toString function using the default TObject.toString + your own class functionality for example if it is a collection class like arrays

Answer (score 0):

The part `activeSet.add(1)` returns a `Set`.  However in this line:

```
 assertEquals("The element(s) were not added!", 1 , activeSet.add(1));
```

You're comparing it to the number 1.  That is not a match because the types aren't even compatible.

Perhaps you meant to take `toString` from the `add` result?

```
 activeSet.add(1).toString()
```

...and then compare that with another String?

```
 assertEquals("The element(s) were not added!", "1", activeSet.add(1).toString());
```

Comment: This is what I had thought. However when I attempted this the test returned the same error statement:    java.lang.AssertionError: The element(s) were not added! expected:<1> but was:<1 >
 at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)

Comment: I miss read what you had written. I had not considered that the value I checked against would need to be set using " ". It works a treat! thank you greatly!

Comment: Yeah, it just a bit hard to read in JUnit's output message because you can't see that they're different types in this case.